# Hyperledger composer DB connection and sample.feature

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm very new to hyperledger composer, how do I know the participant is created (or where can I get the participant registry ) and the transaction has been processed? Also, what is "features/sample.feature" used for? Is it for unit test or something?

Comment: I have another question, can I create a user (participant) in test/sample.js automatically ?

Comment: This question is too general and open-ended. Please describe what you are trying to achieve, attaching code snippets and describing what your expectations are.

Comment: I mean if I am doing a trading app, which file is used to connect DB (where to store users' information), and if there's a new buyer wanna join this trading, how can I add him or her in this network automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I respectfully suggest you spend some time completing the tutorials and reading the documentation. You will find the answers to your questions there.

Start here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

Then, read this:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participantsandidentities.html